# Questions about code for questions : here or on SO?

Tags: discussion, support, migration

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90872/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) has recently be moved from SO to meta, although the people that are using the [r](/questions/tagged/r) tag regarded it as a coding question. Even though all answers included code or links towards code, it has been moved to meta.

I can see why somebody would think this is a question about the SO site (SO was specifically mentioned by the OP), but the intent was broader than that. Reproducible examples are also necessary for bug reports and on other mailing lists. Plus, I use them often while teaching or discussing performance and design issues with colleagues. So I feel this is a genuine coding question. I also flagged it for migration back to SO, but that's probably not going to happen any more...

Therefor my general question : questions like this related to a specific coding language, should they be posted on SO or on Meta? And if you think this is a question for Meta, how should it be formulated to be a good SO question?

Comment: I note that someone has linked to the question from the [Tag Info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) on SO.

Comment: I think I fixed everything... hopefully.  Took the edit made here back to the question on SO, reversed the migration and made the question a wiki.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest the question you refer to belongs on SO rather than Meta for a number of practical reasons:

- It is a question about R programming.  All of the answers were supplied by people in the top user category in the R-tag.
- User reputation (and therefore privileges) do not transfer from SO to Meta.  This means that the normal workflow for editing, flagging and improving the question and answers are disturbed.  This may well be a obstacle to prevent further improvement of the question.
- The [r] tag isn't common between SO and Meta.  This means someone who clicks on [r](/questions/tagged/r) will be transferred to an empty tag wiki entry on Meta, rather than the intended tag on SO.

Yes, I can see the reasons for migrating a question to Meta.  Surely there is something generic about making reproducible examples that spans across languages.

I would argue the test for whether a question belongs on SO vs Meta should be determined by:

- Is the question about the use of SO or any other related site?
- Are the responses in the main limited to a specific language?

If a more generic version of this question is suitable for Meta, then let's create a specific Meta question about the use of examples.  The original question belongs on SO.

Answer (score 4):

The question as it is now seems to better suit Stack Overflow, not a meta site.
It would better suit here if the question was about some guidelines on the type of code snippets to use in questions posted on Stack Overflow, as "How much code should I report in a question I ask on Stack Overflow?"

Answer (score 3):

Although I agree that there are shades of grey here, Meta is a reasonable place for this question - at its heart, the question is about the best way to get solutions to your problems.

Comment: That was how it was posed originally. But it's about coding the reproducible example. The best way to get solutions to your problems is adding a reproducible example (see faq), but how you do that differs for every language. And is not specific to SO.